# Drools can not use a generic type for a function's parameter in DRL

Tags: java, drools

I'm defining the next function on my DRL

```
function void embargarMultiplesCuentasJudicial(ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas, Embargo embargo,BigDecimal montoTotal ,BigDecimal limite) {
    //BODY
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve type ArrayList<Cuenta> while building function. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to find class 'ArrayList<Cuenta>' ]]
```

But I'm importing the ArrayList and Cuenta at top's file

```
import modelo.Cuenta;
import modelo.Embargo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need to not mention what your ArrayList uses in the parameters. The following example works fine for me (it's an ArrayList of a custom Object) :

```
function testFunction(ArrayList al)
{
    System.err.println("Called a function with the ArrayList : " + java.util.Arrays.toString(al.toArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parser fails on parameters with generic types, but it is possible to omit the type and cast in method's body.

```
function void embargarMultiplesCuentasJudicial(List cuentas, Embargo embargo,BigDecimal montoTotal ,BigDecimal limite) {

    List<Cuenta> typedList = (List<Cuenta>) cuentas;

}
```